# Nav-views in html for ionic and angular

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got this piece of code here that doesn't seem to be displaying quite as I'd like. It seems to be displaying view item2 but not item1 for some reason. Is there any reason in particular for this overlap?

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="item1" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-nav-view name="item2" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </div
</section>
```